# Simultaneously enable gzip and $STR_REPLACE in CGI in apache

Tags: apache-http-server, php, gzip

I have a code in my CGI script for text replacement (for example replace 'red' with 'blue')

```
$STR_SEARCH='red'
$STR_REPLACE='blue'
```

I am using the below code in .htaccess for enable replace function:

```
(RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding)
```

This works fine. But when I want to use gzip for compression, gzip does not work. If I disable the replace, gzip works fine. How can I get gzip and replace to work together?